# Why should I use sum()-Function here?

Tags: r

Why should I use the sum()-Function here and not the length() Function?

```
sum(age<=20)/length(age)
```

Age is a vector with numeric values representing the age.

Why should I not use:

```
length(age<=20)/length(age)
```

These function should return the same values, don't they?

Comment: `sum` get the sum of the `TRUE` values, while `length` gives the total length of the vector.  So in essence `length(age<=20)` and `length(age)` will be the same.   These can be tested by a generating a sample data. i.e. `set.seed(24); age <- sample(25, 20, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: A quick read of the help files of each should have clarified this.

Answer (score 4):

No, they shouldn't. The result of:

```
age<=20
```

is a boolean vector with the same dimensions of the variable 'age'. 
Therefore,

```
sum(age<=20)
```

counts how many values are lower than or equal to 20, while

```
length(age<=20)
```

will return the length of 'age'

BTW,

```
sum(age<=20)/length(age)
```

can be more simply obtained via:

```
mean(age<=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're referring to, but, in general principles:

age<=20 is a condition, returning yes/no, and presumably 1/0, on each item (or record)

`sum(age<=20)` will sum up the Ones. It gives you the number of items where the condition is satisfied.

On the other hand, `length` returns a number: the count of your array/vector/recordset. `age` is a vector, `age<=20` is not, it's a boolean expression.

If you ask `length(age<=20)`, you will most likely get `1` as it is the length of the result of `age<=20`, which is a scalar value.

Comment: I hate it when we all reply at the same time :)
But at least we say the same :-D